# Coldfusion Dynamic URL

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I need to build a dynamic url based on two fields I am getting from my database.
The first field is mainCategory and the second is subCategory.

The URL being built looks something like http://mydomain.com/cars/ford

Since mainCategory and subCategory are dynamic, I am not sure what code needs
to appear on the page for this to work.

Comment: Could you clarify on a few parts of your question?

Is cars the mainCategory and ford the subCategory?

Are you asking how to build that link, or how to get the values back when someone tries to use it?

Comment: How to get the values back when someone tries to use it. That is my dilemma.

Comment: For what it's worth, that's generally referred to as a "search engine safe" URL. A web search for "[ses url coldfusion](http://www.google.com/search?q=ses+url+coldfusion)" should provide a number of other resources.

Answer (score 0):

A heavily over-simplified answer could go something like this:

```
<cfquery name="getCats" datasource="dsn">
SELECT mainCategory, subCategory
FROM myTable
</cfquery>

<cfset newURL = "http://mydomain.com/cars/ford/mainCategory/#getCats.mainCategory#/subCategory/#getCats.subCategory#" />
```

In this example, a basic CFQUERY with the name of "getCats" is used to select two columns out of a database table 'myTable'. Assuming there are results, those two values are injected into the URL which we save into a variable called "newURL", to be used elsewhere in your code.

This example can really only be used as a general guideline; there are many additional assumptions not clarified in your question that will need to be addressed (ie. names of databases, tables, DSNs, how the user actually goes to that URL, etc.) not addressed in the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, but I guess the real question I needed answering is how can I use a dynamic url like this to send to a third party user so that they could see the same results. So, I guess I would need to somehow dissect or pull cars and ford from the url and compare it against the table. Is that an option?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. You need to a) Analyze/extract URL information--which requires you breaking down/parsing the location, b) turning those values into information that applies to your particular system (ie. mapping arbitrary 3rd-party URL vars to *your* specific vars that represent the same business objects, and c) passing those values into the CFQUERY above, which would allow you construct a dynamic URL which more closely matches your requirements. Again, there is still the missing part of you feeding that URL *back* to the user, and sadly, more knowledge of the app is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that.  You could use URL rewriting on the web server to turn

http://mydomain.com/cars/ford

into

http://mydomain.com/index.cfm?mainCategory=cars&subCategory=ford

But you can also do it in ColdFusion if you don't mind index.cfm being in the URL like so:

http://mydomain.com/index.cfm/cars/ford

If you want to do it in ColdFusion, the text after "index.cfm" is put into a cgi variable called path_info that you can parse out like so:

```
<cfset mainCategory = "" />
<cfset subCategory = "" />

<cfset pathInfoString = reReplaceNoCase( trim( cgi.path_info ), ".+\.cfm/? *", "" ) />
<cfset pathInfoArray = listToArray( pathInfoString, "/" ) />

<cfif arrayLen( pathInfoArray ) gte 1>
    <cfset mainCategory = pathInfoArray[ 1 ] />
</cfif>
<cfif arrayLen( pathInfoArray ) gte 2>
    <cfset subCategory = pathInfoArray[ 2 ] />
</cfif>
```

You can use listGetAt() instead of converting it to an array, I just prefer doing array operations over list operations.  That reReplaceNoCase() is done because I think in some instances the filename is added to the start of the path info, but you may not need that if it isn't happening for you.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be along the lines of what I need. Converting http://mydomain.com/cars/ford into a way that I can compare it against the table so it can display all the results for Cars and Ford. I just used the code you posted and cfoutput mainCategory and subCategory but it returned nothing. Just blank.

Comment: I had tested this in ColdFusion 9 before posting, but I didn't think there was anything CF9-specific in there.  I had the code in a temp.cfm and used temp.cfm/cars/ford .

If you dump out the pathInfoArray or pathInfoString do you get a value?

Comment: Check what's in your CGI.path_info.  I don't recall the details (but Google will...) but sometimes - and it *could* be with old versions of CF like CFMX7 - it was not populated correctly.  Using mod_rewrite or equivalent would be the best approach to dealing with this, rather than falling back to CF, IMO.